# Decimal point mandatory regex angularts

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

Should only accept decimal characters negative or positive. I want to make decimal point mandatory using regex but it is accepting negative whole numbers which is not intended. Does not accept positive whole numbers which is intended (Ex. -2 is accepted but 2 is not. -2.0 and 2.0 should be accepted.)

So far I have '^([^A-Za-z]-?[0-9]*.[0-9]*)$' which makes sure there are no letters, puts the '-' character as optional and makes sure the '.' character is mandatory (but only for positive need to change the regex so that it is mandatory for negative decimals as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
/^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
```